# What is the best practice to read full POST request body when using REST in Caché?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

Having the following UrlMap:

```
<Routes>
   <Route Url="/SaveSomething" Method="POST" Call="Save"/>
</Routes>
```

What is the best (easiest?) way to read **full** request body, without string length limitations ($$$MaxStringLength) or anything that may cut off some data?

In my case the purpose of this is to place the contents into a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that would work:

```
// %request.Content is a %CSP.BinaryStream
set ^global = ""
while '%request.Content.AtEnd {
   set ^global = ^global _ %request.Content.Read($$$MaxStringLength)
}
```

About [%request](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25CSP.Request)